# Will solar lights around my vegetables and flowers be bad for them?

Tags: vegetables, light, annuals

I have a decent size vegetable garden and various annual flowers in my back yard.

I recently bought some solar lights and put it around the plants. The lights stays on all night long, and I wonder is having a light source around them 24/7 (sun in day time, solar lights at night) bad for plants?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as the plants are concerned, it's still dark at night, unless you spent the price of a house on some **very** abnormally large and bright solar lights.

Comment: nope I did not spend that much, the lights are $3/each simple solar lights. thanks

Comment: In trying to grow stuff that isn't gangly and weak by artificial light, the one thing you learn is how much energy is contained in sunlight. Unless you have a really strong bank of fluorescent grow-lights or halides, it's often a waste of time.